# getting 'ERROR: 'Syntax error in '. castable as xs:integer' while Trying to transform xml, based on Data type of value the tag is containing

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

here is my _ignoreText.xsl file

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
        <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()" >
    
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or ./@* != ''">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
    
            <xsl:variable name="type">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". castable as xs:integer">
                        <xsl:text>Integer</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test=". castable as xs:boolean">
                        <xsl:text>Boolean</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>String</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
    
    
        </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

below is a java code in which i am using above _ignoreText.xsl file to transform xml

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform;
import java.io.File;


public class TransformDemo1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String xsltfilename="D:\\Demo\\src\\test\\java\\StringXml\\_ignoreText.xsl";
        File xsltfile=new File(xsltfilename);

        String strSource = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
                "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +
                "    <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "        <return>\n" +
                "            <ICD10Flag>hello</ICD10Flag>\n" +
                "            <status>success</status>\n" +
                "        </return>\n" +
                "    </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n";
        Transform docSource = new Transform(strSource, xsltfile);

    }
}
```

following is the Error i am getting.

```
ERROR:  'Syntax error in '. castable as xs:integer'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'file:/D:/Demo/src/test/java/StringXml/_ignoreText.xsl: line 18: Required attribute 'test' is missing.'
Exception in thread "main" org.custommonkey.xmlunit.exceptions.ConfigurationException: file:/D:/RijvanPactPOC/2/DemoProjectPactConsumer/src/test/java/StringXml/_ignoreText.xsl: line 18: Required attribute 'test' is missing.
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.getTransformer(Transform.java:201)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.<init>(Transform.java:161)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.<init>(Transform.java:92)
    at StringXml.TransformDemo1.main(TransformDemo1.java:31)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: file:/D:/Demo/src/test/java/StringXml/_ignoreText.xsl: line 18: Required attribute 'test' is missing.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1061)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:817)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Transform.getTransformer(Transform.java:196)
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

please suggest any solution or any other Library using that i can Transform the XML based the data type of the value the xml tag is containing

Ex. 1

```
<status>success</status>
```

should be transformed to

```
<status>String</status>
```

Ex. 2

```
<status>123</status>
```

should be transformed to

```
<status>Integer</status>
```

Comment: i think the message is clear: *Required attribute 'test' is missing.*

Comment: Which is line 18 in your xsl file?

Comment: Thanks @jens but i have already given attribute 'test' on line 18.which is part of Syntex. <xsl:when test=". castable as xs:boolean">

Comment: Souds like you have edited the wrong file or you have not saved the changes

Comment: No, i am sure that i have edited and saved the correct  _ignoreText.xsl file

Comment: You use XPath 2 or 3 with your `castable`, so you need to make sure an XSLT 2 or 3 processor, which in the Java world means Saxon HE (use 11.4 for XSLT 3, use 9.7 for XSLT 2) is on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to match the XML with node content's data type.

If that is the case you can use the custom `DifferenceEvaluator` as below.

```
public class XMLUnitDiffDemo{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  String strSource = "<root><test>true</test>" +
                "<test2>2</test2>" +
                "<test1>1</test1>" +
                "</root>";
  String strTest = "<root><test>true</test>" +
                "<test1>1</test1>" +
                "<test2>2</test2>" +
                "</root>";


 Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(xmlSource).withTest(xmlCompareWith)
                .ignoreComments()
                .ignoreWhitespace()
                .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
                .withDifferenceEvaluator(new DataTypeElementDifferenceEvaluator())
                .checkForSimilar().build();

System.out.println(!myDiff.hasDifferences())
}
}
```

Custom implementation.

```
class DataTypeElementDifferenceEvaluator implements DifferenceEvaluator {

    @Override
    public ComparisonResult evaluate(Comparison comparison, ComparisonResult outcome) {
        if (outcome == ComparisonResult.EQUAL) return outcome; // only evaluate differences.
        Node controlNode = comparison.getControlDetails().getTarget();
        Node testNode = comparison.getTestDetails().getTarget();
        String controlnodename = controlNode.getNodeName();
        String testNodename = testNode.getNodeName();
        String conCN = controlNode.getTextContent();
        String conTN = testNode.getTextContent();
        if(controlnodename.equalsIgnoreCase(testNodename)){
            System.out.println(getDataType(conCN) + " ==  " + getDataType(conTN));
            if(getDataType(conCN).equalsIgnoreCase(getDataType(conTN))) {
                return ComparisonResult.SIMILAR;
            }
        }
        return outcome;
    }

public static String getDataType(String input) {

        String dataType = null;
        // checking for Integer
        if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
            dataType = "java.lang.Integer";
        }
        // checking for floating point numbers
        else if (input.matches("\\d*[.]\\d+")) {
            dataType = "java.lang.Double";
        }
        // checking for date format dd/mm/yyyy
        else if (input.matches(
                "\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}[/]\\d{4}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format mm/dd/yyyy
        else if (input.matches(
                "\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}[/]\\d{4}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format dd-mon-yy
        else if (input.matches(
                "\\d{2}[-]\\w{3}[-]\\d{2}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format dd-mon-yyyy
        else if (input.matches(
                "\\d{2}[-]\\w{3}[-]\\d{4}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format dd-month-yy
        else if (input.matches("\\d{2}[-]\\w+[-]\\d{2}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format dd-month-yyyy
        else if (input.matches("\\d{2}[-]\\w+[-]\\d{4}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for date format yyyy-mm-dd
        else if (input.matches(
                "\\d{4}[-]\\d{2}[-]\\d{2}")) {
            dataType = "java.util.Date";
        }
        // checking for String
        else {
            dataType = "java.lang.String";
        }

        return dataType;

    }

}
```